# Cannot install ros-noetic-moveit-visual-tools on Ubuntu 20.04, WSL2

Tags: ros, moveit, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whilst setting up a machine to control a kuka arm, I've run into a problem setting up ROS noetic with moveit.

This system is being built on WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. After installing `ros-noetic-desktop-full` and `ros-noetic-moveit` without issue, trying to install `ros-noetic-moveit-visual-tools` fails because the package cannot be found.

```
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-moveit-visual-tools]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-moveit-visual-tools
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-noetic-moveit-visual-tools] failed
```

This seems odd since it's a standard part of the other distros I've used, and is still referenced in the current tutorials.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364942/cannot-install-ros-noetic-moveit-visual-tools-on-ubuntu-20.04,-wsl2/) by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9529 on 2020-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> This seems odd since it's a standard part of the other distros I've used

It's actually "just a package", not really anything standard.

Please see #q320046 for the extended version, but in short: according to [status_page/ros_noetic_default.html?q=moveit_visual](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_default.html?q=moveit_visual_tools), that package is currently only available in the [testing repository](http://wiki.ros.org/TestingRepository) (note the red square saying `main: none` on hover).

It's probably been released only recently into Noetic, and until a "sync" is performed for Noetic, it will not be available from the main repositories.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2020-11-06**:
Okay, Thanks. I'll include it in the package directly in that case.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-06**:
Switching to the testing repository is a 5 min affair. I'd avoid building from source if at all possible.